# What was Vision doing in this scene?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

In *Captain America: Civil War*, Vision keeps Wanda confined to the Avengers compound as requested by Tony Stark. Later, en route to join Captain America, Clint Barton (aka Hawkeye) picks Wanda up at the compound. But Cap probably already told him that Vision was watching her, so as a distraction, Clint set off some kind of explosion some distance away from the compound to get Vision to come out to investigate. [This is the scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYzk0OOSCAo) where the explosion happens and Vision is in the compound.

[image: A still frame of a really dark scene in which we can see Vision floating near the corner of a room. In the middle of the room are two chairs facing each others, along with a tiny round table between them.]

So my question is, what was Vision doing in this scene? He seems to be floating in mid-air, in the dark, in an empty room, doing nothing? This is obviously not the room where Wanda was, because as you can see in the next scene, he phases through the floor of the room where she is to join her.

This is clearly a different room, with what looks like a kitchen as well, whereas the room where Vision was in previously looked more like a sitting room on a lower level.

So if Vision was meant to watch Wanda, what was he doing on a different level of the compound, in the dark, just floating in mid-air?

Comment: Could you perhaps provide the clip that you took screenshots of?

Comment: Floating in a darkened room? I should imagine he's sleeping. Or chilling

Comment: @ASH-Aisyah: What can I do to improve my answer for you?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots, thank you for your answer. But as you said, there's not really much proof/justification...

Comment: Frustratingly, the Junior Novelization cuts off before this point and they apparently never wrote more. I've checked out the BluRay copy of the movie and I'll see if they do any commentary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My belief is that they're trying to emphasize his robotic nature, which helps contrast against his all-too-human desires regarding Wanda and how it drives his passion. Someone not moving conjures the idea of an inanimate object. Floating emphasizes his unworldliness. As regards him watching Wanda, presumably he was tapping into cameras in the facility, until he rose into her room to personally assure her. He could do that from any place, but by not being in the same room, he's ostensibly giving her privacy and space.

That said, this is my interpretation of how they set it up, versus any sort of answer with justification.

Comment: But the whole point of the movie was to show how he was leaning more towards his human side. And even for a 'robot', he had his own room in the compound (presumably), he knew where Wanda was, and he hardly ever just floats alone in a dark room doing nothing... It doesn't seem to fit in with any of his other scenes...

Comment: I'd argue that emphasizes that human side by the contrast. There he is, being inhuman, and then suddenly he's in Wanda's room and being compassionate, followed by his jealousy and struggle with his feelings for her resulting in War Machine getting shot out of the sky.

Answer (score 0):

He absolutely was in" guard duty" mode...or " 1st watch" mode.... He had no need to be looking out a Window like a human guard watch would, or no need to be planted in front of a panel of security camera displays (as he is able to tap into them wirelessly). He was basically in a watchful "airplane mode" lol.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).